# ORA-06508 Error on 10G form with 11g Database

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

We are currently running oracle 10g Application server with 10g developer suite but with a 11g database.

When we compile a form while connected to our 11g database and run it on the 10g application server, we get a ORA-06508.  We have traced this to a call to a package that is contained within the form (not a atached PLL or in the database).

When we compile against a historic 10g database everything works exactly as it should.

call is just...

pkg_name.procedure_name;

and specification of this package is

procedure_name(arg1 varchar2(100) default null);

We cannot continue to compile against the old database, Any assistance in trying to track this error would be appreciated.

Comment: We have now narrowed this down to packages on the form that use types....  eg variable type := new type()

Answer (score 0):

Are you connecting the 11g database to the user who is the owner of the package for executing? In that case or even if you are connecting to different user to execute the pkg,I'm suspecting the synonym is missed for this package.

Generally for this ora-06508 - From my experience only 3 possible issues
1)package not exist
2)package exist but in invalid status
3)Synonym is missing for that pkg

Could you tyr after create synonym package_name for pkgowner.package_name

Comment: Thanks for the comment but as stated in the original question, the package is not in the database.....  It is on the form itself.  We have worked out that it is happening when the package on the form accesses an object type in the database.  There is some difference in the way these are accsessed in 10g and 11g......